How do I include a .h file, located in an upper level directory? С++
So, for instance I have a bunch of files:
root-dir:
  dir-a:
    read.cpp
  dir-b:
    code.cpp
  lib.cpp
  lib.h

lib's files:
//lib.cpp

#include <string>
using namespace std;

string edit(string in) {
    string out;
    /*function body*/
    return out;
}

//lib.h

#include <string>
std::string edit(std::string in);

I need to include lib's function in both "read.cpp" and "code.cpp".
I tried to:

#include "lib.cpp" from both files, but it failed: fatal error: lib.cpp: No such file or directory

#include "lib.h" . Same: fatal error: lib.h: No such file or directory

#include "root-dir/lib.h", it highlights red: 'root-dir/lib.h' file not found


Obviously, #include "C:/.../.../root-dir/lib.h" is not a proper solution.

Include-paths in double-quotes "" are relative to the current source files location. So if code.cpp needs to include ../lib.h then that's the path it should use: #include "../lib.h".

On a different note, don't #include source files. Set up your build-system to be able to build separate source files into object files, and link them into the executable program.

In general you don't solve directory dependencies in your source code, but you do that in your make files. Which build system do you use? Because in the end you should be able to write something like #include <yourlib/lib.h> (eg have a file structure root_dir/include/yourlib/*.h) and let the build system pass root_dir/include to your compiler.

Side note : also unlearn to use using namespace std;

For very small projects, #include "../lib.h" is a quick-and-dirty solution.  Does not scale well.  Very fragile.  Use Pepijn's advice for any non-small project: that avoids baking upwards or lateral path traversals into your source code (which makes it very hard to reorganize your code, or share your code, or segregate your code into separate subprojects).

Thanks everyone for the advice, I'll try to figure out how to pass root directory to the compiler later. For now "../lib.h" is enough.

You can include lib.cpp by writing #include "../lib.cpp" here, but there are a few things to note:

You should always include header files, not source files.

A better approach would be to organize header and source files in separate folders. Here is an example:
.
├── inc
│   └── lib.h
└── src
    ├── code.cpp
    ├── lib.cpp
    └── read.cpp




This still would need proper setup of the build environment e.g. makefiles
